# iTerm2 click to open selected path

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2, iterm

```sh
➜  ~ brew remove proxifier
==> Uninstalling Cask proxifier
Error: It seems there is already an App at '/usr/local/Caskroom/proxifier/2.22/Proxifier.app'.
```

Here's a common log, which contains a path and iTerm2 recognizes it, we can quickly open that path by holding down the <kbd>Command</kbd> key and clicking on it.

But what I want to ask is if there is a way to quickly open a selected part of the path. For example, when I use the cursor to select `/usr/local/Caskroom/proxifier`, is there any built-in way to quickly open it in the Finder in iTerm. For example, open it by clicking on it with <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd>. I know this can be done with Automator, but before do that I'd like to know if there is a built-in way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Hold the command (⌘) key on your keyboard and click on a filename or a path, it tries to open it. This can be enabled or disabled in [iTerm2 Preferences](https://www.yurikoval.com/blog/2016/02/open-a-file-with-atom-from-iterm2-using-command-click.html#:%7E:text=One%20of%20the%20lesser%20known,or%20disabled%20in%20iTerm2%20Preferences.)